# Creating file 'php' after getting data

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

. I wonder how can my project automatically create php file by itself , after getting some data like product description ?

Comment: Can I ask why you want to create a PHP script like this?

Answer (score 1):

Like you'd create any other file. From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php). Just give it a `.php` extension.

Comment: yeah gacha ! thx